# How to install a downloadad package in qpython3

Tags: qpython3

Iam just downloaded some python package from pypi.org. Then iam tried to install the packeges to qpython3. But i can't Do it
`import numpy`
`ModuleNotfoundError:no module named numpy`is a way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question with further specifics and context to make it easier understand and answer. Which packages have you installed, and how?

Comment: Numpy and some other. I first downloaded it using pypi. I want know to install them

Comment: Please update your question, providing the exact commands/procedure you have used to a) install and b) attempt to use the packages.